# Android RecyclerView Sticky Header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, stickyrecycleview

I want to make recyclerView with sticky header without external libaray

and I refer to [this](https://medium.com/@saber.solooki/sticky-header-for-recyclerview-c0eb551c3f68). Everything is work.

But when I change the header with some alpha, something went wrong

The header will duplicate when the view overlay.

[Here is the demo video](https://imgur.com/a/Y4hqzuz)

[screen shot]
`2023-08-01` is duplicate

[image]

[Here is the source code](https://gist.github.com/saber-solooki/edeb57be63d2a60ef551676067c66c71)

How to solve it.